# Начало использования среды NetBeans IDE 7.3.1

Tags: c, netbeans

Пишу для проверки:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main(){

    printf("hello");

}
```

выводит мне вот это:

```
"/C/mingw/msys/1.0/bin/make.exe." -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk QMAKE= SUBPROJECTS= .build-conf
make.exe.[1]: Entering directory `/c/Users/���������/Documents/NetBeansProjects/CppApplication_1'
"/C/mingw/msys/1.0/bin/make.exe."  -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk dist/Debug/MinGW-Windows/cppapplication_1.exe
make.exe.[2]: Entering directory `/c/Users/���������/Documents/NetBeansProjects/CppApplication_1'
mkdir -p build/Debug/MinGW-Windows
make.exe.[2]: mkdir: Command not found
make.exe.[2]: *** [build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/main.o] Error 127
make.exe.[2]: Leaving directory `/c/Users/���������/Documents/NetBeansProjects/CppApplication_1'
make.exe.[1]: *** [.build-conf] Error 2
make.exe.[1]: Leaving directory `/c/Users/���������/Documents/NetBeansProjects/CppApplication_1'
make.exe.": *** [.build-impl] Error 2

СОБРАТЬ FAILED (значение выхода 2,, общее время: 952ms)
```

Как быть? Заранее благодарен.

Comment: Чтобы из Netbeans/Eclipse работал С/С++ нужно прицепить к нему т.н. toolchain - а их по сути 2: MinGW и CygWin - какой выбрать дело вкуса. В сети немало примеров как прицепить тот или иной toolchain к NetBeans'у или Eclipse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Судя по логу и строке

> make.exe.[2]: mkdir: Command not found

компилятор не находит путь к команде `mkdir` (не может создать каталог). нужно использовать не `windows` команду а ее опенсорсную версию (из комплекта `MinGW`).

Вот вопрос схожий с вашим: [MingW Netbeans 6.9.1 problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5224381/mingw-netbeans-6-9-1-problem).

Comment: Попробуйте добавить **в начало** environment переменной PATH путь к mingw\\bin и mingw\\msys\\1.0\\bin

Answer (score 0):

Думаю стоит сюда добавить 
NetBeans - среда разработки, выполненная в виде Java-приложения. 
Для изменения количество ресурсов, предоставляемых этому процессу необходимо изменить конфигурацию общую или локального пользователя.

```
{program_dir}\etc\netbeans.conf
{user_dir}\etc\netbeans.conf
```

Далее - меняем настройки производительности JVM
Ищем строку

```
netbeans_default_options="-J-client -J-Xss1024m -J-Xmx2048m -J-XX:PermSize=3000m...
```

- `-J-Xmx` - максимальный размер кучи приложения JVM NetBeans
- `-J-Xms` - первоначальный размер кучи, как раз изменение этого показателя загружает среду быстрее, 
  когда JVM уже выделила кучу для процесса.

Весь материал отсюда: [netbeans.conf params](http://bit.ly/16PbbC4)